# Epson et-4760 setup on Ubuntu 20.04 - no driver found

Tags: 20.04, printing, epson

I have an Epson ET-4760 on my network connected via ethernet cable.  My Ubuntu-20.04 laptop sees the printer, but cannot find a driver for it.  I have a Win10 virtual machine running as guest on this laptop and it prints to the Epson with no problem.

Why can't Ubuntu 20.04 find a driver for the Epson ET-4760?

Comment: It was asked "Why can't Ubuntu 20.04 find a driver for the Epson ET-4760?". This is very perplexing! Give what you get for `driverless`.

Answer (score 1):

On the latest Mint the printer was found without any problems, but you can easily install the "driver," that is a CUPS PPD file, from Epson:

https://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/?OSC=LX

If you prefer you can reach that page via the main product support page:

https://epson.com/Support/Printers/sh/s1

The only file you need to get started is the "ESC/P-R Driver 2 (generic driver)." The printer utility doesn't work. It uses some very old QT libs, and even if you install those there are other missing components. Not sure if the fax driver works or not.

For scanning, skip the version 2 All-in-One package on that page, and download the version3 deb from here:

https://support.epson.net/linux/en/imagescanv3.php

Since yours is networked, see Section 7 of the installation manual (linked at the top of the page).

Comment: Hm..., "latest Mint" is not Ubuntu. Don't know why post this here.